# Html file in footer setting of customer portal is not working on Summer'16?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, css, summer-16

I have used html file in footer setting of customer portal and it is working fine. but today sandbox is updated into summer 16 and its JS and css is not working. Please help me how to use css/Js in footer setting of customer portal in Summer 16 release.

Here is my footer Page

```
<span id="hideMyParent">
</span>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#sidebarDiv #hideMyParent').parent().parent().hide();
  var startYear=1900;
  var endYear=2020;
  var optionsString='';
  if(startYear<endYear){
  for(i=startYear;i<endYear+1;i++){
  optionsString += "<option value=\""+i+"\">"+i+"</option>";
  }
  $('#calYearPicker').html(optionsString);
  }
  $('#sidebarDiv #hideMyParent').parent().parent().hide(); });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var t;
var currenturl = location.href ;
 window.onload=resetTimer;
 document.onkeypress=resetTimer;
 document.onmousemove=resetTimer;

function logout()
{
   if(currenturl.toLowerCase().indexOf("main/sitelogin") == -1){

        alert("Your session has timed out. Please login again.")
        location.href='https://'+window.location.host+'/'+'main/secur/logout.jsp'

    }     

}

function resetTimer()
{
    clearTimeout(t);
    t=setTimeout(logout,1800000) //logs out in 30 minutes
}
</script>

<div id="wrapper" class="two-col-left width-940 two-col-left-940">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/main/resource/styles" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" />
  <div id="header" class="col-full">
    <div id="logo"> <img src="/main/resource/test" alt="Test.com" />
      <span class="site-description">INTEGRATED WORKFORCE SOLUTIONS DESIGNED WITH A PASSION FOR EMPLOYEE PRIVACY
        <span class="site-description2">
           &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Contact us: 4.123.123.1331
          <br>
            XXXXXXX
          </br>
        </span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
<div style="padding:0; margin-bottom:60px; background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #f5f9fa;">
</div> 
<div id="content" class="col-full">
  <div class="shadow-t">
  </div>
<div class="shadow-r">
</div>
<div class="shadow-l">
</div>
<div id="main-sidebar-container">
  <script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var tu = document.createElement('script'); tu.type = 'text/javascript'; tu.async = true;
    tu.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'dpi1c6z6qg9qf.cloudfront.net/client/v3/tutorialize.js.gz'
    var sc = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; sc.parentNode.insertBefore(tu, sc);
  })();
  var _t = _t || [];
  _t.push = function(){if(typeof window.tutorialize !== 'undefined'){window.tutorialize.process(arguments[0]);}
  return Array.prototype.push.apply(this, arguments);};
  _t.push({publisher_id: '5293a2624e5fe1bcd800013c'});
  </script>
  <script>_t.push({start:'Quick Invite'});
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: This is where your stylesheet is supposed to be located: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/main/resource/styles" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" />`. You've not included it in the code above and I don't see any references to a footer. It's most likely in one of the JS scripts that's referenced in your code. Please take the time to visit the [Help] and read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).